# Tring to get condition.operator by Expression Language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, el

I am using the following code to get condition object by REST API.

This object has operator and response fields.

I am trying to use these fields in an `if` statement like:

```
if(response condition.operator condition.response)
```

`condition.operator` should be `<`, `>`, `==` or `else`.

How can I get `condition.operator` using Expression Language?

Full code

```
Condition.getCondition({id:id}).$promise.then(function(condition){
    if(response  condition.operator condition.response){
        console.log("")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable as an operator like that.
However you can try this approach:

condition.operator is a function, for example:

```
function(a, b) { return a + b }
```

Then you call it like this:

```
if(condition.operator(response, condition.response))
```